# Xcode Autolayout - Constraint equal to another constraint

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, autolayout

I am finally trying to adopt autolayout in IB and I am having trouble setting the constraints for some objects. I basically want 5 views to be equally distributed vertically throughout the superview. I have 3 buttons separated by 2 lines. I want the spacings D1, D2, D3, and D4 to be equal **WITHOUT** resizing the height of anything. How can this be set up in IB?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create `UILayoutGuide` objects (or, for iOS versions before iOS 9, `UIView` objects) for D1, D2, D3, and D4, e.g., `spacer1`, `spacer2`, etc., and then define their heights to be equal to each over. In Visual Format Language (VFL), the vertical constraint would look something like:

```
@"V:|-[button1][spacer1][separator1(4)][spacer2(==spacer1)][button2][spacer3(==spacer1)][separator2(4)][spacer4(==spacer1)][button3]-|"
```

I don't know how you're representing your separator lines (here I'm just using a 4 point tall `UIView`, but you can do it any way you want). But hopefully this illustrates the idea.

If you were doing this in Interface Builder, you can add `UIView` objects in between the visible controls, and then select all of the spacer views (e.g. by shift-clicking) and then add a constraint to pin the "Heights Equally" to make them all the same height.

You can achieve a similar effect programmatically without the spacer views by creating a constraint on the `NSLayoutAttributeCenterY` attribute of each button and separator line and adjusting the `multiplier` value for each such that they're evenly spaced. The effect is very similar, but not identical.

Comment: Nice simple solution to do this visually.