# Center a view without a container view?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

Using constraint, is it possible to vertically center a view in storyboards without creating a container view?

[image: vertically center image in storyboard]

*Update*: To be clear, I want the describe the vertical centering with constraints, so that it will remain vertically centered on device screens with different sizes. (i.e. I don't want to manually make the top and bottom constraint the same value.)

Comment: Sorry; had to go look up my old solution for this; forgot that I had to add spacer views and then say the spacer views are the same height. (You can make two views the same height, but you can't make two constraints the same size in IB.) For how to do this in code, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768513/xcode-autolayout-constraint-equal-to-another-constraint

Comment: You can do it without a *container* view.  It depends on why you are asking: 1) you don't want to create any additional views, or 2) you don't wan't the image to be a subview of yet another view.  If the second, then you can create a sibling view of the image view that spans the space between the label and the bottom, and then constrain centerY for this view and your imageView to be equal.  Rob's spacer views would be a second way of doing it without a *container* view.

Comment: The reason to not use container (or spacer) views is that it feels wrong to use visual objects that are not visible. Apple added `UILayoutGuide`s in iOS9, which eliminate the need for adding views that are not visible. Sadly, they don't seem to be fully available in storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible without writing code

Comment: ok, I guess I shouldn't feel so bad about using container or spacer views.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make any container and also you want to handle from storyboard then you can take a view in middle between them with one pixel and give centre vertical alignment, trailing , leading and height. Attached both UILable and UIImageView with this UIView from top and bottom. 
I think your problem might be solve.